# Bulkify existing flow to avoid SOQL Limits?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, governorlimits, bulkification

I currently have a flow that looks up and passes the ID of a Fire Department into an object called Service Plan. The Fire Department is found by looking up the `BillingCity` on the Account associated with the Service Plan.

I am wondering if anyone can help me Bulkify this flow so I can insert over 100 service plans at a time without running into a SOQL Limit?

I have about 5 flows that all have this problem so I am hoping if someone can help me out here, I can fix the others too.

Below are screenshots of my flow which functions perfectly when creating a single record using the Lightning UI.
The values for `varRecordID` and `varCity` are being set in Process builder

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do i create a Fast Lookup to Service Plans and then loop through those service plans?  or Do i create a Fast Lookup to Fire Departments and then loop through the service plans?

Comment: Do you have any other flow or trigger on that object? Usually its combination of both that causes too many SOQL issue

Comment: Yeah, I have 3 or 4 other flows on that object but shouldn't they not be counted because their processes are not being invoked?

Comment: If the case is that I have another flow on the same object that is conflicting. What is the best way go about fixing this issue? To ensure that I do not run into limits?

Comment: Just like triggers, you need to think of flows in terms of 1 flow/object when it comes to bulkification.